# How to know what the solution will look like in a PDE (Seperation of Variables)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I ran across a PDE problem in which they have
$$\dfrac{\partial u_1}{\partial t}=\dfrac{1}{r} \dfrac{\partial}{\partial r}\bigg(r\dfrac{\partial u_1}{\partial r}\bigg)$$
With initial conditions and BCs of
$$\text{IC } u_1(r,0)=-(1-r^2) $$$$\text{BCs } u_1(1,t)=0 \qquad \dfrac{\partial u_1}{\partial r}(0,t)=0 $$
They then assume $$u_1(r,t)=T(t)R(r)$$
I am really not sure why this is even true and even more unsure how to approach it. I understand the idea that if the equation is homogenous, you can set both functions equal to a constant which makes sense because one function depends on one variable and the other depends on the the other and they are equal. I am not seeing anything like that here though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the method of separation of variables.

The point is that *some* solutions, but not *all* solutions, can be written in product form $u_1(r,t)=T(t)R(r)$. If you plug this into the PDE and do a tiny amount of manipulation, you have the form (some function of $t$) equals (some function of $r$). Put them both equal to a constant, and you end up with two ordinary differential equations, one for each of the two variables.

Since the equation is linear, any linear combination of product solutions will be another solution. The magic lies in the fact that this leads to a general solution of the equation, under fairly lax conditions.

To reiterate: Nowhere is the claim made that any solution must have the product form. Just that these can be used as building blocks for more general solutions.

Comment: How do you know which solutions qualify to be written in such a way?

Comment: You mean, as a product? You can answer that question by plugging the product form into the PDE and solving for the two functions. I don't think there is a quicker way.

Comment: So another words you make a guess and you find out if it's true by solving 2 ODES right?

Comment: Yep. Except the “guess” is supported by plenty of exerience with these equations.